# AIX Non GNU tool for text replacement

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

Contents of the file :

```
PS1="$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} "
PS1="${FGOLD}$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} ${NORMAL}"
PS1=abd
PS1="$(hostname):$LOGNAME:\$PWD $PROMPT "
export PS1 LANG
```

Lines I want to change :

```
PS1="$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} "
```

replacement line :

```
PS1="${FGOLD}$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} ${NORMAL}"
```

Comment: OK, since you have completely changed the original question, we need to know more. Are there any other lines that match `PS1`? If so, what should we do with them?

Comment: server is a AIX box...    yes there will be other PS1 inside the file...  but this above pattern alone has to be replace with below pattern...

Comment: If there are more similar lines that need to be excluded, we need to see them to know how to identify the lines you do want changed. We can't read your mind and we don't have access to your data. You need to show us the files in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed 's/^PS1="\$(hostname).*\${PROMPT}.*/PS1="${FGOLD}$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\\\${PWD} ${PROMPT} ${NORMAL}"/'
```